# Is there a way to create a function that changes booleans values based off array?

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, boolean, variable-assignment

I have different installation prompts in my script that can be toggled by boolean values. Each respective boolean I want to put into a container data-type like a array so that I can categorize & later modify them. More specifically, **I want to modify my booleans from within that array/list using a function.** Do I have to modify the items using a index value or something instead of the iterable value i? Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash
# this is example code based off my installation script.
INSTALL_GIMP=0
INSTALL_KRITA=0
INSTALL_VLC=0
images_array=($INSTALL_GIMP $INSTALL_KRITA $INSTALL_VLC)

enabling_prompts() {
arg1=$1
for i in ${arg1[@]} ; do
    echo "$i"
    i=1
    echo "$i"
done
}
# ^ I want a function like this to change the given array's booleans to 1.
# I want to use modifiable arrays to make it easier when adding 
# -more categorized "programs" to the prompt script.

enabling_prompts $images_array

while [[ $INSTALL_GIMP == 1 ]]
do
echo "This is skeleton code. I need to change the values to 1 so that this code can be run."
done
```

Comment: "Do I have to modify the items using a index value or something instead of the iterable value i?" Yep!

Comment: @JohnKugelman thanks for replying! I have done this sort of thing in Python but not in Bash. I will try to see if I can get this code working.

Comment: Bash has associative arrays -- dictionaries, in Python lingo. Check them out, they're a good fit for what you're doing.

Comment: `the given array's booleans to 1.` But the array contains _values_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store boolean into an associative array and access the array by reference within the function:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Associative array of boolean
declare -iA images_array=(
  ["gimp"]=0
  ["krita"]=0
  ["vlc"]=0
)

# The array name is passed by reference as argument 1
enabling_prompts() {
  # array is a reference name (Need Bash 4.2+)
  local -n array="$1"
  for prog in "${!array[@]}"; do
    printf -v prompt 'Install %s (Y)es|(N)o?\n' "$prog"
    while read -r -p "$prompt" answer; do
      case "$answer" in
        [yY])
          array["$prog"]=1
          break
          ;;
        [nN])
          break
          ;;
        *) :
          ;;
      esac
      :
    done
  done
}

# ^ I want a function like this to change the given array's booleans to 1.
# I want to use modifiable arrays to make it easier when adding 
# -more categorized "programs" to the prompt script.

enabling_prompts 'images_array'

for prog in "${!images_array[@]}"; do
  if [ "${images_array["$prog"]}" -eq 1 ]; then
    printf 'Installing %s...\n' "$prog"
  else
    printf '%s will not be installed!\n' "$prog"
  fi
done
```